# MySQL selecting specific values but still want to include rows that doesn't matches the condition

Tags: mysql, accounting

I am working with the database of a journal entry voucher management system. I have a journal_entry table with 517 rows. I select the table with a jev no = '2022-03-001'

```
SELECT
    jev_no, account_code, debit, credit
FROM
    journal_entry
WHERE
 jev_no ='2022-03-001'
```

and the returned rows are:

| jev_no | account_code | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-001 | 50501010 | 800.00 | 0.00 |
| 2022-03-001 | 20201010 | 0.00 | 800.00 |
| 2022-03-001 | 10102010 | 0.00 | 521.00 |
| 2022-03-001 | 20201070 | 521.00 | 0.00 |

**I want to filter these specific values in the table:**

1. Include account_code = 10102010 with credit > 0
2. Exclude account_code = 20201010
3. Include account_code = 20201070  with credit > 0
4. Exclude account_code = 50299990  with credit > 0
5. Exclude account_code = 50213040  with credit > 0
6. Exclude account_code = 10305010  with credit > 0

but if a row doesn't match the condition, it should still be included in the result

Then I tried to filter the table with

```
SELECT
    j.jev_no, j.account_code, j.debit, j.credit
FROM
    journal_entry j
WHERE

         (account_code = 10102010 and j.credit > 0)
        AND account_code <> 20201010
        AND (account_code = 20201070  and j.credit > 0)
        AND ( account_code <> 50299990  and j.credit > 0)
        AND (account_code <> 50213040  and j.credit > 0)
        AND (account_code <> 10305010  and j.credit > 0)
and jev_no = '2022-03-001'
```

But there are no rows returned.

Result should be:

| jev_no | account_code | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-001 | 50501010 | 800.00 | 0.00 |
| 2022-03-001 | 10102010 | 0.00 | 521.00 |

**Because:**
The `account code` `20201070` should be excluded because the `credit` value is not greater than 0.
The `account code` `20201010` should also be excluded.

Comment: @Paul T. He has `but if a row doesn't match the condition, it should still be included in the result` as an implicit `include all` at the end of check list . So basically I believe he's using the blacklist approach, thus the individual `include account_no` clauses are not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Include` and `Exclude` are mutually exclusive in this case.  From your intention, you have 2 `include account_code` and 4 `exclude account_code`. What about the rest of the account_code which are not covered by those 6 ? Should you include or exclude the rest? Based on your request ***but if a row doesn't match the condition, it should still be included in the result*** ,it means you would like to include the rest, then what use are those 2 `include account_code` for? Why not just have the 4 `exclude account_code` and include the rest ? From my point of view, we should use  a blacklist approach (specify the `exclude account_code` and include the rest) here.

```
SELECT
    jev_no, account_code, debit, credit
FROM
    journal_entry
WHERE
 jev_no ='2022-03-001'
 and (not (  account_code = 20201010
            or ( account_code = 50299990  and credit > 0)
            or (account_code = 50213040  and credit > 0)
            or (account_code = 10305010  and credit > 0)
          )
     )
;

-- result set:
# jev_no, account_code, debit, credit
2022-03-001, 50501010, 800.00, 0.00
2022-03-001, 10102010, 0.00, 521.00
2022-03-001, 20201070, 521.00, 0.00
```

Last, please check your expected output, as it does not add up based on your rules.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes, I would like to include the rest which is not covered by those 6 conditions. I agree about that I should use only exclude  account_code. It makes my query simpler and readable. I didn't think about that idea, maybe I really need to get some good sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first change all the conditions to exclude and try to select items not in the excluded list.

```
SELECT
    j.jev_no,
    j.account_code,
    j.debit,
    j.credit
FROM
    journal_entry j
WHERE
    j.account_code NOT IN(
    SELECT
        account_code
    FROM
        journal_entry
    WHERE
        (
            account_code = 10102010 AND j.credit <= 0
        ) OR account_code = 20201010 OR(
            account_code = 20201070 AND j.credit <= 0
        ) OR(
            account_code = 50299990 AND j.credit > 0
        ) OR(
            account_code = 50213040 AND j.credit > 0
        ) OR(
            account_code = 10305010 AND j.credit > 0
        )
) AND jev_no = '2022-03-001'
```

[image]